# Posterior distribution for gamma distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, learning, gamma-distribution

Im given the question:

---

Given that the Gamma distribution likelihood
$$p(y|β) = Gamma(y; α, β) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{Γ(\alpha)} y^{α-1} e^{(-βy)}$$

where α is a positive constant and β > 0 is unknown. We place a Gamma prior over β,
Gamma(β; α0, β0) as the conjugate prior. Prove the posterior distribution can be written as
Gamma(β; α0 + α, β0 + y).

---

So I do the following:

$$\text{posterior} : p(β|y) \propto p(y|β) \cdot p(β)$$

$$ p(y|β) \cdot p(β) =\frac{\beta^\alpha}{Γ(\alpha)} y^{α-1} e^{(-βy)} \cdot \frac{\beta_0^{\alpha_0}}{Γ(\alpha_0)} β^{α_0-1} e^{-β_0 \cdot β} $$

Simplifies to:

$$ \frac{β_0^{α_0}\cdot y^{α-1}}{Γ(\alpha_0 + \alpha)} β^{α+α_0-1} e^{-β(β_0+y)}$$

And then Im stuck... anybody have a tip or two to share?

Comment: You have already done it.  $p_{\text{posterior}}(\beta\mid y)\propto \beta^{\alpha+\alpha_0-1}e^{-\beta(\beta_0+y)}$ and you should recognise this as the Gamma density with parameters $\alpha+\alpha_0$ and $\beta_0+y$.  I think part of your problem is that you retain silly normalisation constants from $p(y\mid\beta)$ and $p_{\text{prior}}(\beta)$ that doesn't depend on $\beta$ obscuring what is really important.